# Query for greater/less than in combination with other field asks for already existing index

Tags: google-app-engine

I got an index like this for my entity Word:

> changed ▲ + type ▲

I've added one entity to the datastore and can successfully query it in the console like this:

> KIND Word
>
> changed is a number greater than 0

However if I add a second field to the filter like this:

> KIND Word
>
> changed is a number greater than 0
>
> type is a string that is noun

It will fail with the error "You need an index to execute this query."

It seems to me that the exact index it's asking for is already present. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Do you have an entry for this custom index in your datastore-indexes.xml/yaml file?  If you do, can you show it?  If not, you need it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to query on two fields you need a combined index, not an individual index on both of them.

Please review this for more information about Datastore indexes:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get ALL the indexes you need is to run the queries on your devserver, making sure you hit EVERY query you can do on production.

When you're in development, the dev server will create all the indexes needed for your application in you xml/yaml (java/python).  If you didn't hit that particular query on your devserver, the index is not in your xml/yaml and you'll need to add it manually.

It's a paradigm shift when you're working with the datastore, but you have to understand that, for scalability reason, the datastore CANNOT do ANY computation.  It only returns you scans of your table.  When you save one Entity in your table, behind the scene the datastore will actually save it multiple times, one for each index, already sorted for that index.  So even if you have your index for parameter 1 AND a separate index for parameter 2, it will not necessarily create the composite index for parameter 1 & 2.  So if you don't create that composite index in your xml/yaml, you "force" the datastore to do a join between your tables, which it unfortunately cannot.

I took it as a best practice to hit EVERY query I can do with my code in the dev server and then look at my indexes created.  You just have to be careful not creating tons of indexes since they work on your quota and can end up costing you(if your app has billing enabled of course).